# How to access child elements without knowing the parent in firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

How to access child elements without knowing the parent in firebase realtime database? How to get data by userId without knowing the parent.

This is my [database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRPSw.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `following` node is a direct child of your Firebase root, to display the values of `followCase`, `parentId` and `userId` properties, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference followingRef = rootRef.child("following");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
                String followCase = ds.child("followCase").getValue(String.class);
                String parentId = ds.child("parentId").getValue(String.class);
                String userId = ds.child("userId").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", followCase + " / " + parentId + " / " + userId);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
followingRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
0 / B4RV...NI73 / P3y8...8NO2
//and so on
```

Comment: thanks, brilliant solution